# Valid method does not clear error message if it returns true

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I submit empty form, and one field is invalid. Than I change something in my form (not for current, invalid field) and invoke validation for my invalid field in code:

```
$('.myinvalidfield').valid()
```

It returns me that this field is valid, but doesn't remove validation error message for it. What should I do to fix it? (I dont want to remove messages and error classes by hand. It is possible to do using settings or JQuery?)

*Update.*

I have two fields, first element is not required, second is required only when first is empty. I use this rules:

First, required field:

```
    required: function (element) {
        var secondElement = $(selector);
        var value = secondElement.val();
        return value == ""; //if second (not required) field has value, that current element is not required
    },
```

Second, not required field:

```
    required: function (element) {
        var secondElement = $(selector);
        if (secondElement.length == 0) return false; //becouse my forms builds dynamicly
        secondElement.valid(); //invoke validation for required field
        return false;
    }
```

This rules works, but if I submit the form with empty fields it show me one error for reqired field, and when I change first, not required field, then all form is valid, but the error message is not disappear from second element.

Comment: With this plugin, [_by default_, errors _automatically_ clear themselves](http://jsfiddle.net/d55hj/), so you must have changed something critical.  Where is the rest of the code?  Show your jQuery `.validate()` function and the relevant HTML.

Comment: Even with the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` options disabled, the errors clear themselves out when `.valid()` is called.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/d55hj/1/

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Typically we don't put complex functions inside the `required` rule... just a `true`, `false` or `depends` function.  Please construct a jsFiddle of this in action.

Comment: You will not be able to control the second field's message through interaction with the first field's error.  In other words, you have to interact with the field that contains the error in order to clear it out.  Your alternative is to create a custom method where you'll have better control over everything.  See my answer for a demo of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all errors automatically clear out when the field is made valid.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d55hj/**

---

**EDIT**:

As per OP:

> "I have two fields, first element is not required, second is required
>   only when first is empty."

Try this simplified version...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field2: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#field1').is(':blank');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d55hj/4/**

---

Otherwise, you would have to [create a custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) to have more precise control over everything...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('customrule', function (value, element) {
        if ($('#field1').val() === "" && $('#field2').val() === "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            $('label.error').hide();
            return true;
        }
    }, "Please fill out field #2 when field #1 is empty");


    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        groups: {  // use 'groups' option to combine both error messages into one
            name: "field1 field2"
        },
        rules: {
            field1: {
                customrule: true
            },
            field2: {
                customrule: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d55hj/7/**